# Algebra problem related to calculus and binomial formula

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

This might look like a trivial calculus question, but I did tons of calculation 
 and research to turn the property I am interested into this simple form (actually it would be a sufficient condition of some property that I'm interested in)

For where this problem comes from, check this: [Sum of Binomial random variable CDF](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271471/sum-of-binomial-random-variable-cdf)

Consider the following quantity:
$$
(1-p)^{n-2}-(1-q)^{n-2}+(n-2)q(1-q)^{n-3}-(n-2)p(1-p)^{n-3}
$$
where $n\ge4$ is an integer, and $q-p\triangleq c$ is supposed to be fixed, i.e., the quantity can also be written as:
$$
(1-p)^{n-2}-(1-p-c)^{n-2}+(n-2)(p+c)(1-p-c)^{n-3}-(n-2)p(1-p)^{n-3}
$$

How can I show that this quantity is positive for $p\in (1/n-c/2,2/n-c/2)$?

Simulation shows that this quantity is decreasing in the given interval, so I tried taking derivative w.r.t. $p$, trying to show it's negative and solve the problem by plugging in $p=2/n-c/2$, but it gives a quantity similar as the quantity of interest, so either it doesn't really help, or I'm missing something here.

I have also tried using binomial formula, but couldn't get anything meaningful also.

Any suggestion and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit 1: Restriction on $c$: $c\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Any restriction on $c$? Your quantity is zero when $c=0$.

Comment: Could be "no", unless $c>0$.

Comment: If c is small enough (and positive), the answer is yes. In particular,  an elementary analysis shows a yes answer if p+c is less than 2/(n-1). I recommend defining t and f with t=1-p and f such that your expression is f(t)- f(t-c).  If c is larger so that p+c is larger than 2/(n-1), then more work is needed.  I guess that if c is near p in size, the answer is no.  You could also graph it using Wolfram alpha's website. Gerhard "Try Math.Stackexchange For This Problem" Paseman, 2017.06.15.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch, Edited the question, $c>0$

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan, you're right, I forgot to put the restriction on $c$ there

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, why? Isn't this for questions encountered in research? I did huge amount of calculation in my research and turned the property I wanted to show into this question...

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, I did the simulation with R using multiple settings, and it seems that the result is right. In addition, the quantity becomes bigger as $c$ increases. Also you're absolutely right, when p+c<2/(n−1)p+c<2/(n−1), the result is kind of trivial, so I was kind of more worried about the other case, as that was what I could not solve